# In React dangerouslySetInnerHTML is not working for html tags.

Tags: html, reactjs, markup

In React dangerouslySetInnerHTML is not working for html tags. it is not even working on homepage of [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/). Type `<h1>this is heading.</h1>` [image: Snippet from React homepage]

How can i render html tags in React? Why did we pass * for `<em>` tags in React tutorials ?

Comment: @Alexander Thanks. Answer was so obvious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On `React` homepage example they use [`markdown`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown)*(`markdown` does not understand HTML syntax)* and library [`Remarkable`](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/remarkable)., if you want to use only HTML remove `Remarkable` from `rawMarkup` method - `{ __html: this.state.value }`

```js
var HTMLEditor = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {value: 'Put here <h1>HTML</h1>'};
  },
  
  handleChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({ value: e.currentTarget.value });
  },
  
  markup: function() {
    return { __html: this.state.value };
  },
  
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="html-editor">
        <textarea
          onChange={ this.handleChange }
          defaultValue={this.state.value} />
      
        <div
          className="html-editor__content"
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ this.markup() }
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<HTMLEditor />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

```css
.html-editor {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
}

.html-editor__content {
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```